# "Unknown Type Name N" error even though N is Defined As Constant

Tags: c, syntax-error

I am trying to compile the code below, and I am getting two errors on the line that reads `void assert (n%64==0 && l%64 == 0);`. One error says "unknown type name 'n'" and the other says "Expected ')'". Neither of these make sense to me, because there are no open parentheses that are unclosed, and I define 'n' above with the line `const unsigned n = 2048;`.

I should note, this code comes from a 2013 paper by Daniela Frauchiger, Renato Renner, and Matthias Troyer; which can be found at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4547.pdf. It is part of a randomness extractor for use with hardware random number generators. The code is not mine, but I am trying to adapt it to a project I am working on.

```
const unsigned n = 2048; // CHANGE to the number of input bits, must be multiple of 64
const unsigned l = 1792; // CHANGE to the number of output bits, must be multiple of 64

// the extraction function
// parameters:
//  y: an output array of l bits stored as l/64 64−bit integers
//  m: a random matrix of l∗n bits , stored in l∗n/64 64−bit integers
//  x: an input array of n bits stores as n/64 64−bit integers

void extract (uint64_t * y , uint64_t const * m, uint64_t const * x)
{
    void assert (n%64==0 && l%64 == 0);

    int ind=0;
    // perform a matrix−vector multiplication by looping over all rows
    // the outer loop over all words
    for (int i = 0; i < l/64; ++i) {
        y[i]=0;
        // the inner loop over all bits in the word
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 64; ++j) {
            uint64_t parity = m[ind++] & x[0];
            // performs a vector multiplication using bit operations
            for (unsigned l = 1; l < n/64; ++l)
            parity ^= m[ind++] & x[l];
            // finally obtain the bit parity
            parity ^= parity >> 1;
            parity ^= parity >> 2;
            parity = (parity & 0x1111111111111111UL) * 0x1111111111111111UL;
            // and set the j−th output bit of the i−th output word
            y[i] |= ((parity >> 60) & 1) << j;
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to C, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I have not been able to answer it from existing answers.

Comment: Sometimes the result of a function is cast to void with `(void)` (note the parentheses), either to explicitly ignore the return value or (probably more often) to silence warnings from a code-style tool.  But `assert` _has_ no return value, so I think this case is just a mistake.

Comment: The problematic `void` is not in the original code example on p.20 of the PDF.   You might want to check your code for other typos, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void assert (n%64==0 && l%64 == 0);` is trying to declare a function alled assert, but it is in the wrong place. Just remove the `void` and now you are calling the "debug function" `assert` to check that `n` and `l` meet their required constraints.

```
void extract (uint64_t * y , uint64_t const * m, uint64_t const * x)
{
    assert (n%64==0 && l%64 == 0);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add follow headers on top of your code:

```
#include <stdint.h>  // uint64_t
#include <assert.h>  // assert
```

Change

```
void assert (n%64==0 && l%64 == 0);
```

To

```
assert (n%6==0 && l%64 == 0);
```

Comment: I think the only headers required for the function shown are `<assert.h>` for the assertion and `<stdint.h>` for the `uint64_t` type.

Comment: Still missing `<stdint.h>`...  Although, come to think of it, the headers would have caused completely different error messages from the ones bbernicker is reporting.  He or she probably just didn't include the `#include` statements in the M-almost_C-VE.